# Cannot get past step 2 of Shopify OAuth process

Tags: oauth, shopify

We are able to get past step 1, which returns us a temp_token or code.
When we try to invoke the URL for step 2, we get a "page not found"
response. Below is a sample of the URL we are generating and posting to
in order to get past stage 2.

> https://schmidt-auer-and-wiegand460.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token?client_id=f7f660f4015c7438fb36b66f21562c2c&client_secret=redacted&code=6f8d6ddbb130b663648d0076e35ff3b7

Comment: you may get a better response if you post more details, like the code you use for generating the url, also tagging the question with tags relating to your software environment will help get more attention.

Comment: You need to send the parameters in the POST body, not as part of the query string!

Answer (score 0):

As Jan mentioned it looks like you're passing your params in the query string, GET-style.

You need to make a POST request to that endpoint, and place the parameters in the body of the resquest.

Comment: Hi, I am now getting a http 400 error when I try to post the request. Here is the function attached.